# linking library .a and library .lib

Tags: c++, static-libraries, codeblocks

Good morning,

I need your help please.
I developed a C++ code in codeblocks and I used 2 external libraries (.lib) to calculate the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of complex matrices. I linked these libraries (.lib) in the compiler linker settings as shown in the picture.
[image]
After that, I created a static library (.a) from this code.
My question is the following :
when I will use this library (.a) in another software, this library will link directly to the external libraries(.lib) or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A static library `(.a)` can be used as it is. So if you use this static library with another software, it will be linked to the same external lib. You can see it as a `zip` format from sources, so you can just keep the `.a` and use it where you want to.

But I recommend you to always keep your external library files and create the static library at compilation time. I don't know if you're compiling with a `Makefile` or a `CMakeList`, if you do you can configure it to create the static library during the compilation.

See `ar` command. [`ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar)

Comment: a last thing plz.  in fact i didn't use a Makefile or a Cmakelist. I used codeblocks to generate my static library (.a) just like this (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZKJl4Hj1NuH-dl40IXJHSnpJKmVl3s5E). it's generated in the  release folder and it's composed of (.o) files as shown in this pic (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-FxpbWgjycaTTRfV1hTcHA5dEZXU3B1dzNBYm9iWDNXaVdZ). so the libraries (.lib ) that i used have no object in my static library (.a). i dont know if it will work correctly !